# Re-index two digit strings based on occurrence of a common string

Tags: awk, sed, grep, gnu-sed

I have a `urlwatch` `.yaml` file that has this format:

```
name: 01_urlwatch update released
url: "https://github.com/thp/urlwatch/releases"
filter:
  - xpath:
      path: '(//div[contains(@class,"release-timeline-tags")]//h4)[1]/a'
  - html2text: re
---
name: 02_urlwatch webpage
url: "https://thp.io/2008/urlwatch/"
filter: 
  - html2text: re
  - grep: (?i)current\sversion  #\s Matches a whitespace character
  - strip # Strip leading and trailing whitespace 
---
name: 04_RansomWhere? Objective-See
url: "https://objective-see.com/products/ransomwhere.html"
filter:
  - html2text: re
  - grep: (?i)current\sversion #\s Matches a whitespace character
  - strip #Strip leading and trailing whitespace
---
name: 05_BlockBLock Objective-See
url: "https://objective-see.com/products/blockblock.html"
filter:
  - html2text: re
  - grep: (?i)current\sversion #(?i) \s 
  - strip #Strip leading and trailing whitespace
---
```

I need to "re-index" the two digit number depending on the occurrence of `name:` . In this example  the first and second occurrence of `name:`  are followed by the correct index numbers but the third and fourth are not.

In the example above the third and fourth occurrence of `name:`  would have their index number re-indexed to have `03_` and `04_` before the text string. That is: a two digit index number, and an underscore.

Also, there are instances of this string `#name:`  which should not be counted in the re-indexing. (They have been commented out so those lines are not acted upon by `urlwatch`)

I tried using sed but had trouble with generating an index number based on occurrence of the string. I don't have GNU sed but can install if that is the only method.

Comment: Do not use `sed`. I believe, this could be done in an awk script - match the expression, replace with `gsub` with a new number, output.

Comment: If you are on macOS, install GNU sed and GNU awk anyway, or else you lose a lot of features using their broken defaults (confirmed by SO mac users). `sed` is not suitable for this job also, as Kamil already said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
awk '/^name/{sub(/[0-9]{2}/,sprintf("%02d", ++c))}1' file
```

For any line starting with "name" we replace the first 2-digit number with our counter, which increments on every occurrence, with the help of the GNU awk [`sprintf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function to print it with leading zeros when needed.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. It does exactly what it's supposed to do!

Comment: Nice. Also in the future consider to always use GNU awk and GNU sed, in case you don't have them both for your OS, I guess you can install them.

Comment: Thanks for this. Far more advanced and intricate than I could handle. I will install with homebrew... `brew install gnu-sed; brew install gnu-awk`

Answer (score 3):

I think this could be ok:

```bash
awk '/^name: / { sub(/[0-9]{2}/, ++i); sub(/ [1-9][^0-9]/,"\x0&"); sub(/\x0 /," 0") }; 1' your_input
```

On every line starting with `name:` , we substitute the double digit (`[0-9]{2}`) with a number `i` after incrementing it (it starts from undefined, i.e. from 0, so the first time we increment it we get 1); with another substitution we mark the line if if there's a one digit number only, and with a third substitution we add a leading 0 and remove the mark.

Probably it's a bit fragile, but given your explanation, it looks fine.

Comment: I just need a two digit index number. That's what I asked. The commands you wrote skips to a three digit number after 10 and then between every additional ten:        01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 20, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 30,....  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @John, I think it's fixed now, fwiw.

Comment: I did have a couple of upvotes on this question at one point. I guess someone came along and downvoted me. I don't think it's simple for a novice CLI user.

Comment: Downvotes come everywhere, even on the best questions. However, does my fix work now?

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^name:/{x;s/.*/expr & + 1/e;s/^.$/0&/;x;G;s/[0-9]+(.*)\n(.*)/\2\1/}' file
```

Match on a line beginning `name:`, increment a counter in the hold space, append the hold space to the pattern space, match on first set of integers and using captured groups substitute the counter.